# XSLT not matching - namespace tempuri.org Crypto

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, cryptography, xml-namespaces

Help much appreciated!

Crypto is a French real estate XML specification. I am working from a 1 record, test XML file.

Can anyone tell me why the following XSLT works when I remove the Crypto XMLNS declaration from the XML input file, but does not when I include it?

**XML WITH NAMESPACE REMOVED THAT OUTPUTS CORRECTLY**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/CryptML.xsd">  
    <DESTINATAIRE>    
        <AGENCE>      
            <BIEN>
                <REFERENCE>43</REFERENCE>        
            </BIEN>      
        </AGENCE>
    </DESTINATAIRE>
</ROOT>
```

**XML WITH WORKING XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
    <DESTINATAIRE>    
        <AGENCE>      
            <BIEN>
                <REFERENCE>43</REFERENCE>        
            </BIEN>      
        </AGENCE>
    </DESTINATAIRE>
</ROOT>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/DESTINATAIRE/AGENCE/BIEN"> 
        <COL><DATA><xsl:text>This is a test</xsl:text></DATA></COL>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <COL>
        <DATA>This is a test</DATA>
    </COL>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a default namespace in your XML, then all elements belong that namespaces. This makes them different to elements that are not in a namespace, even if they have the same name in the XML.

Your XSLT makes no reference to the namespace. It is looking for elements in no namespace, and so won't match elements that do belong to a namespace.

The solution is to declare the namespace in your XSLT, and use it to match the elements in that namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
                              xmlns:cml="http://tempuri.org/CryptML.xsd">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="cml:ROOT/cml:DESTINATAIRE/cml:AGENCE/cml:BIEN"> 
        <COL><DATA><xsl:text>This is a test</xsl:text></DATA></COL>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use the "xpath-default-namespace" property, which allows a default namespace to apply to xpath expressions, removing the need to explicitly set a prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
 xpath-default-namespace="http://tempuri.org/CryptML.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/DESTINATAIRE/AGENCE/BIEN"> 
        <COL><DATA><xsl:text>This is a test</xsl:text></DATA></COL>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks indeed. This problem was causing me many headaches!